# Display Admob banner in bottom of IOS device

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am developing an Application in Xcode using cocos2dx.In my Application I want my admob banner to display in Bottom of the screen, for that I am using the following code. It moves the game content to top and displays the banner in bottom. But I want the banner in bottom without moving the content. The banner is displaying in top without moving the content. please advise me to correct my mistake.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
CGRect bannerFrame = CGRectZero;
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0
bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
#else
bannerFrame.size = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];
#endif

bannerFrame.origin.x = (contentFrame.size.width - bannerFrame.size.width) / 2;

////To display the banner in Bottom

if (_bannerLoaded) {
    contentFrame.size.height -= bannerFrame.size.height;
    bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
} else {
    bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
}


////To display the banner in top

//    if (_bannerLoaded) {
//        bannerFrame.origin.y = 0;
//    } else {
//        bannerFrame.origin.y = -bannerFrame.size.height;
//    }

_contentController.view.frame = contentFrame;
_bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}
```

Comment: bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height -bannerFrame.size.height;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above coding make Some changes in the if condition like this.

```
if (_bannerLoaded)
{
contentFrame.size.height = 0;
bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height-bannerFrame.size.height;
} 
else 
{
bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height-bannerFrame.size.height;
}
```